# Xcode does not found symbols for architecture x86_64 using XCFrameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ios-simulator, xcframework

Xcode (11.2.1 & 11.3.1) is having issues to found x86_64 architecture symbols while using XCFrameworks. The problem is that the architecture is inside the XCFramework, but first let me show you how the framework was created.

To generate the XCFramework I made two Archives:

1. For iOS:

   `xcodebuild archive -scheme MyPod -target  MyPod -destination="iOS" -archivePath build/ios.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/iphoneos -sdk iphoneos SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES`
2. For iOS Simulator:

   `xcodebuild archive -scheme MyPod  -target  MyPod -destination="iOS Simulator" -archivePath build/iossimulator.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/iphoneos -sdk iphonesimulator SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES`

Then I generated the XCFramework:

`xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework ./build/ios.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyPod.framework -framework ./build/iossimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyPod.framework -output xcframework/MyPod.xcframework`

Here is the XCFramework created where we can see the two architectures:
[XCFramework preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EyvK.png)

Once it was created, I distributed it by Cocoapods (1.9.0.beta.3). So my .podspec looks like:

`s.subspec "Vendored" do |framework|
    framework.vendored_framework = 'xcframework/MyPod.xcframework'
  end`

Then I consumed it in another project, and when compiling, it fails because it can't find the architecture for the simulator (on devices it works)

The log I got is the following:

`ld: warning: ignoring file /Path/To/MyProject/Pods/MyPod/xcframework/MyPod.xcframework/ios-armv7_arm64/MyPod.framework/MyPod, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Path/To/MyProject/Pods/MyPod/xcframework/MyPod.xcframework/ios-armv7_arm64/MyPod.framework/MyPod (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$MyPod", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SomeClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

It's looks like xcodebuild always go to the `ios-armv7_arm64` folder instead the `ios-i386_x86_64-simulator` one, Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @marco there is a cocoapods issue looking foward to solve this. Link : https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9525

Comment: @LeandroFuryk did you manage to find a way out?

Comment: Same problem.I guess you have swift and objc file in mix?

Answer (score 0):

Hey please generate with `-sdk`  flag with this [combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592295/xcframework-issue-a-library-with-the-identifier-ios-armv7-arm64-already-exist/63750854#63750854):

```sh
xcodebuild archive -workspace IVTNetworking.xcworkspace  -scheme IVTNetworking \
 -configuration Debug  -sdk iphoneos  \
 -archivePath '/Users/chitaranjans/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives /IVTNetworking.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive' \
 SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

This works fine as expected.