# XCFramework issue, A library with the identifier "ios-armv7_arm64" already exists

Tags: swift, xcode, xcodebuild, xcframework

While creating XCFramework, I'm getting the below-mentioned message on the terminal and xcframework is not getting generated
`A library with the identifier "ios-armv7_arm64" already exists.`

This is the command that I'm running

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework ./archives/My-iOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/My.framework \
-framework ./archives/My-iOS-Simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/My.framework \
-output My.xcframework
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: hey u got any sol in this @NoobDeveloper

Comment: @TheCodeTalker Got the solution but now facing other problems, check out my solution and see if it works

Comment: yes I also solved what other problem you are facing let me know I can help

Comment: @TheCodeTalker My framework works in iOS13 but in iOS12 it doesn't work, this happens only when build libraries with distribution flag is true, if it is false, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Updated my script with the below-mentioned script, now this particular problem is solved but facing other problems. Those who are facing this issue can try out the script and see if it works.

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme FrameworkName -destination="iOS" -archivePath /tmp/xcf/ios.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/iphoneos -sdk iphoneos SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES


xcodebuild archive -scheme FrameworkName -destination="iOS Simulator" -archivePath /tmp/xcf/iossimulator.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/iphoneos -sdk iphonesimulator SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES


xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework /tmp/xcf/ios.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/FrameworkName.framework -framework /tmp/xcf/iossimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/FrameworkName.framework -output FrameworkName.xcframework
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete and rebuild the original frameworks and try running the xcodebuild command again.

Answer (score -1):

It Create a problem when you are trying to combining same frameworks twice . just refer the list and generate as per platforms [image]